# Detect when user taps on a notification while app is in foreground

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

`userNotificationCenter(...,didReceive,...)` and `userNotificationCenter(...,willPresent,...)` are used respectively to:

- handle when the user **taps** on a notification while the app is in the **background**
- handle when the phone **receives** a notification while the app is in the **foreground**.

But how do we handle the event in which the user **taps** on the notification while the app is in the **foreground**? (to, for instance, take the user to the relevant view controller when tapping on the notification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two *didReceive* methods, and they act differently.
As it says on [the page for the didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application):

> "Unlike the [application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate/1428430-application) method, which is called only when your app is running in the foreground, the system calls this method when your app is running in the foreground or background."

Comment: I hadn't realised that `userNotificationCenter(...,didReceive,...)` stilled got called when you tap on the notification, even if `userNotificationCenter(...,willPresent,...)` has just been called because the app is in the foreground. Thanks!